# How can I view repositories by activity in bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

The drop down list has recent activity but it shows only the most recent five

Comment: Your dashboard shows all the activities and related repositories, right?

Comment: It shows the repositories but not in chronological order.  It shows all the activity but that is too much information.  I just want repositories sorted by activity

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime (October 2012), [Bitbucket completely changed their site design](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/10/09/introducing-the-redesigned-bitbucket/).

In the new design, the standard list of your repositories is sorted by activity, displaying the repository with the most recent activity on top.
The direct URL is https://bitbucket.org/YOUR_NAME/profile/repositories ([example](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/profile/repositories))